# Extraer la columna anterior completa dependiendo de la columna actual recorrida

Tags: java

Tengo un array bidimensional que se ve así:

```
String[][] tableData = 
{
    {-, -, -, -, -, -, -, -}
    {-, -, -, -, -, -, -, -}
    {-, -, -, -, -, -, -, -}
}
```

Y deseo que dentro de un loop que recorre las columnas, extraer solo la información de la columna actual - 1 (es decir la penultima), (cuando digo la información de una columna me refiero a la columna completa), algo como esto:

Asumamos que i vale 4 en el loop por el momento, entonces la columna a extraer sería esta:

```
String[][] tableData = 
{
   {-, -, esta, -, -, -, -, -}
   {-, -, esta, -, -, -, -, -}
   {-, -, esta, -, -, -, -, -}
}
```

Y guardar esta información en orden dentro de un vector en el ciclo:

```
for(int i = 1; i < tableData.length; i++){

   //No comenzar desde el 0, siempre quiero 'mirar' hacia lo anterior.
   //Esta vector almacenaría la información de la columna anterior entera:   
   String[] lastCols = new String[tableData.length];

}
```

Como puedo extraer la columna anterior entera dependiendo de la columna actual recorrida?

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer? ¿Llevar cada fila del tablaData a un arreglo de objetos de tipo `String[]`?

Comment: Si sorry, en el ejemplo tengo dos arrays uno llamado rsStream y otro lastColsStream, la idea es que lastColsStreams enrealidad sea un String[] que me almacene las columnas de esa fila de acuerdo a cual fila se esta recorriendo actualmente, ademas lastColsStreams, no almacenaría las columnas enteras de una fila, si no que almacenaria las columnas desde 0 hasta n - 1 (penultima columna que esta siendo recorrida) en cada iteración, este es el motivo de hacer un map, (se me olvido mencionar que el ultimo codigo esta encerrado en un for), el cuál recorre un numero fijo de cols que hay en la tabla.

Comment: Por ejemplo si el numero de columnas recorridas en el for es 8, y se esta recorriendo la 4, entonces almacenar las columnas desde 0 a3 de la actual fila que este siendo recorrida en orden, donde las filas y columnas las representa el array bidimensional tableData, la idea es que lastCols almacene las columnas de la actual fila desde 0 a n - 1, para dentro hacer operaciones con estas columnas.

Comment: Pero para eso no necesitas usar un map. Por ejemplo, puedes definir un arreglo de tipo `String[]` (llamado `cols`) y luego a través de un bucle, recorres las columnas de X fila de la matriz `tableData`. Ejemplo: `for(int i = 0; i != tableData[0].length; ++i) cols[i] = tableData[0][i];` El tamaño del arreglo `cols` debe coincidir con el número de columnas de la matriz `tableData`. Y listo, con esto puedes hacer cualquier operación con dicha fila.

Comment: En el ejemplo solo asigna los objetos de tipo `String` de la primera fila (index `0`). Ahí se puede crear algún método en la cual le puedas pasar el número de filas que quieras o ejecutar todo de una vez a través de un bucle principal y agregas todo el código que mencioné anteriormente como un bucle anidado

Comment: Gracias, hice lo que me recomendaste y erá justo lo que necesitaba, me ha funcionado... me estaba complicando un poco con algo innecesario...

Comment: Si editas la pregunta y especificas bien el problema (lo que realmente necesitabas), podría dar una respuesta, puesto a alguien más le podría servir...

Comment: Listo amigo, creo que ahora ya es mas adecuada la pregunta, creo que podrás considerar una respuesta ahora ;3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder obtener la información de X columna para después almacenarlo en un arreglo de objetos de tipo `String[]`, habría que hacer 2 cosas:

**1.-** Especificar el tamaño del arreglo, en la cual, debe coincidir con el número de filas de la matriz `tableData`.

**2.-** Recorrer a través de un bucle cada fila de X columna.

Entonces lo único que debemos hacer es crear un método llamado `getDataColumn`, en la cual nos retornará un arreglo de objetos (de tipo `String[]`) con la información de X columna.

En código quedaría así:

```java
public class Program 
{
    static String[][] tableData =
    {
        {"1", "2"},
        {"3", "4"},
        {"5", "6"}
    };

    public static String[] getDataColumn(int col)
    {
        String[] datas = new String[tableData.length];
        for(int i = 0; i != tableData.length; ++i)
            datas[i] = tableData[i][col];
        return datas;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) 
    {   
        datas = getDataColumn(1);
        for(String data : datas)
            System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

En ese ejemplo se imprime por pantalla la segunda columna, dando como resultado lo siguiente:

```java
2
4
6
```

Si por alguna razón se necesitara de algún método en la cual nos retorne un arreglo de objetos con la información de X fila, el proceso sería inverso:

**1.-** Especificar el tamaño del arreglo, en la cual, debe coincidir con el número de columnas de la matriz `tableData`.

**2.-** Recorrer a través de un bucle cada columna de X fila.

En código quedaría así:

```java
public class Program 
{
    static String[][] tableData =
    {
        {"1", "2"},
        {"3", "4"},
        {"5", "6"}
    };

    public static String[] getDataRow(int row)
    {
        String[] datas = new String[tableData[0].length];
        for(int i = 0; i != tableData[0].length; ++i)
            datas[i] = tableData[row][i];
        return datas;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) 
    {
        String[] datas = getDataRow(2);
        for(String data : datas)
            System.out.println(data);
    }
}
```

Dando como resultado:

```java
5
6
```

Answer (score 0):

Si entendí correctamente tu pregunta, y lo que quieres es convertir un `Object[]` que contiene todos `String` dentro, puedes usar `.asList(T... a)` seguido de `.toArray(T[] a)` como en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
Object[] objectArray = new Object[] { "a", "b", "c" };
String[] stringArray = Arrays.asList(objectArray).toArray(new String[0]);
for (String string : stringArray) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

Comment: De hecho ahora que caigo en cuenta tengo un error... pero bueno... mi objetivo enrealidad es crear un arreglo de strings[] en base a un arreglo de strings[][] de acuerdo a una condición, por eso uso map, pero mi condición depende de un indice de iteración en este caso... y no sabria realmente de donde sacar este indice, y flatMap no me ayuda.